# How to correctly insert a parameter into an existing sql query to avoid SQL Injections

Tags: sql-injection, prepared-statement

I have seen some answers already but my query is a little bit different:

Here is an original query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(Table1.UserID) from Table1 INNER JOIN 
Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID where Table1.Userid = " + UserID + " and
Table1.Number != '" + Number +"' and Table2.ID < 4";
```

Here is a modified query for SQL Injections:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(Table1.UserID) from Table1 INNER JOIN 
Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID where Table1.Userid = @userId and
Table1.ID != @Number and Table2.ID < 4";
```

If you can notice, the first query has `UserId` surrounded by double quotes: `..." + UserID +"...` and  `Number` us surrounded by single and double quotes: `...'" + Number + "'...`

Here is how I'm setting parameters:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", Number); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId",UserID);
```

where `UserID` is an integer and `Number` is a string.

So, my question is, if the modified query formatted the right way? Is there any difference how to put `@UserId` and `@Number` parameters into a query considering the different ways they are specified in the original query?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on .net Mvc for a long time, and I can ensure you the parameters are correctly fixed by yourself in the second case, and you do not need to worry. By the way you can still debug and test if you can inject yourself. Briefly, your code looks great and invulnerable.

This is how i do it, which is similar and also as safe as yours:

```
    string Query = @"select a1, a2, a3, a4 from table1 where a1 in 
                           (select b1 from table2 where b2 = @start or b2 = @end)";

            using (SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand(Query, Conn))
            {
                Comm.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = start;
                Comm.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.Int).Value = end;
            }
```

Comment: but what is the difference between having two different ways of appending parameters to  a query? Why parametarized query handles integer `@UserID` and string `@Number` the same way? In original query `Number` is appended as `'" Number "'` and `UserID` is appended as `" UserID"`?

Comment: Their way of declaring parameters, has their own way of checking sql injection which nobody has access to read it. It may be something like they may be checking the or 1 == 1 and most of cases they use in sql injection. Just a suggest on how they may have done it.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case if one variable is a string and another is a n integer, the way I used `AddWithValue` will work? What realy bothers me is  that one parameter is appended with double quotes, which is an `Integer` - `" + UserID + "` and another parameter is appended with a double quotes inside of a single quotes, which is a string - `'" + Number +"'`

Comment: Yes your code will work. And, the appearance of the quotes is formed that way so the msSql query parser won't have any problems I guess, since its only string, and not using their library to parse it. Good luck :)

Comment: Should I use `command.Prepare` before executing parametarized query?

Comment: No you don't need mate. You just make sure Connection.Open() is opening.

Answer (score 1):

In your initial query, the double quotes belonged to the actual text of the query, not the parameter.  The single quotes you would add when appending a string into the sql query.  I do not know why you would put single quotes around something called Number.  If in fact that is a numeric type variable, it can go into the query without the single quotes.  But if it has single quotes, the only thing that happens is that Sql sees it as a string, and then converts it to a number if it is going to use it as one.  For example, if Table1.Number is numeric.

But, as you have noted, building your query string by appending your parameters into your query string is terrible practice as it opens the door, wide open, for sql injection attacks.  So, you go with parameterized queries, as you have.

In parameterized queries, you do not worry about quotes.  For parameters that are string values, the environment will worry about encasing them in quotes as it builds the command to pass to your sql db.  For parameters that are numeric, quotes are not needed, and again, that is taken care of for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your 2nd version of the query is much better and from the looks of it, it should work just fine.

Adding parameters instead of concatenating your values is much safer against sql injection. And in this example, and I can't see any way to do a sql injection.

**EDIT**

When using parametrised queries, you dont need to add any quotes, just like when you declare a variable and use it in a query - you dont need to use quotes.

```
DECLARE @x CHAR(10) = 'abc'
SELECT  @x
```

When using concatenation of values inside a query, if the value you're trying to add into the query is a `CHAR`, you need to wrap it between single quotes. If it's an `INT`, it shouldn't be wrapped between single quotes.

```
SELECT  'abc', 1
```

The double quotes you have in your first query dont have anything to do with the sql statement, they are used in your c# code to build the sql statement string you're trying to assign to CommandText.

```
string abcVar = "abc";
int intVar = 1;
string sqlCommand = "SELECT '" + abcVar + "', " + intVar;
```

Comment: So, basically, it does not matter how values are appended into a query? By parametarizing the query, either between double quotes or between  single quotes, the sql statement will be executed fine?

Comment: See my edit above, i hope it answers your questions.